# Character Set mismatch in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.07 The two subqueries below run correctly on their own. All I'm trying to do is union them together but Oracle gives an ORA-12704: charcter set mismatch error. I have checked similar posts to check the UNION syntax and I don't understand where the error is coming from. The select statements are selecting fields from the same columns in both queries so there should be no data type problems.

```
    SELECT assessmentid,
       claimdate,
       firstdiagnosis,
       affectedsystemdesc,
       thirdparty,
       SUM(settledamount) AS sam,
       param
  FROM (
  SELECT x.xclaimassessment.assessmentid,
         x.xclaimassessment.thirdparty,
         x.xclaimassessment.firstdiagnosis,
         x.xclaimassessment.affectedsystemdesc,
         x.xclaimassessment.claimdate,
         x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice.settledamount,
         'Q1' AS param
    FROM x.xclaimassessment left
    JOIN x.xclaimtreatment
  ON x.xclaimassessment.assessmentid = x.xclaimtreatment.assessmentid
    LEFT JOIN x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice
  ON x.xclaimtreatment.treatmentid = x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice.treatmentid
   WHERE ( ( icd9 = '501'
      OR icd9 = '162' )
     AND thirdparty = 'N' )
     AND months_between(
    SYSDATE,
    TO_DATE(
      x.xclaimassessment.claimdate
    )
  ) < 25
)
 GROUP BY assessmentid,
          claimdate,
          firstdiagnosis,
          affectedsystemdesc,
          thirdparty,
          param
UNION
SELECT assessmentid,
       claimdate,
       firstdiagnosis,
       affectedsystemdesc,
       thirdparty,
       SUM(settledamount) AS sam,
       param
  FROM (
  SELECT x.xclaimassessment.assessmentid,
         x.xclaimassessment.thirdparty,
         x.xclaimassessment.firstdiagnosis,
         x.xclaimassessment.affectedsystemdesc,
         x.xclaimassessment.claimdate,
         x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice.settledamount,
         'Q2' AS param
    FROM x.xclaimassessment left
    JOIN x.xclaimtreatment
  ON x.xclaimassessment.assessmentid = x.xclaimtreatment.assessmentid
    LEFT JOIN x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice
  ON x.xclaimtreatment.treatmentid = x.xclaimtreatmentinvoice.treatmentid
   WHERE months_between(
    SYSDATE,
    TO_DATE(
      x.xclaimassessment.claimdate
    )
  ) < 25
)
 GROUP BY assessmentid,
          claimdate,
          firstdiagnosis,
          affectedsystemdesc,
          thirdparty,
          param
HAVING SUM(settledamount) > 50000;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Off topic: Still i am wondering why Oracle database devs/admins most off time make the aliases. table and column names all uppercase, making the query harder to read because you can't directly see the difference between identifiers like table names, column names and syntax like SQL keywords and SQL functions.

Comment: Show the table structures for all the tables involved.. "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Basically I'm teaching myself this in work and the guy I replaced used CAPS. So figured it was good practise. I prefer lower case for the reason s you mentioned (namely readability) so maybe I'll switch.

Comment: are there any nchar, nvarchar, or nclob columns involved? Also, if you'd like, i can reformat the query for Raymond can have an easier time reading it. one last PS, version 3.1 is 6 years old now...

Comment: thatJeffSmith yes there is an NVARCHAR2 (1 CHAR) column which is the problem. I will post the solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so credit to my manager Mr K who actually solved this.

The problem was with the THIRDPARTY column which is the same data type in both subqueries. In order to solve the problem we used CAST (*field* AS VARCHAR(3)) in both subqueries.

We identified the problem field by stripping all but the first field out of the queries and then adding them back in one by one until it broke.

**What we still don't understand is why this error occured so any information on this would still be apprieciated.** Here is the resolved code:

```
SELECT ASSESSMENTID,CLAIMDATE, FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, THIRDP, SUM(SETTLEDAMOUNT) AS SAM, PARAM
FROM (
      SELECT X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.ASSESSMENTID, CAST(X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.THIRDPARTY AS VARCHAR(3)) AS THIRDP,
      X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, 
      X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.CLAIMDATE, X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE.SETTLEDAMOUNT, 'Q1' as PARAM
      FROM X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT
      LEFT JOIN X.XCLAIMTREATMENT
      ON X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.ASSESSMENTID = X.XCLAIMTREATMENT.ASSESSMENTID
      LEFT JOIN X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE
      ON X.XCLAIMTREATMENT.TREATMENTID = X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE.TREATMENTID
      WHERE ((ICD9 = '501' or ICD9 = '162') and THIRDPARTY = 'N')and MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,to_date(X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.CLAIMDATE))< 25)
      GROUP BY  ASSESSMENTID, CLAIMDATE, FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, THIRDP, PARAM
      UNION
SELECT ASSESSMENTID, CLAIMDATE, FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, THIRDP, SUM(SETTLEDAMOUNT) AS SAM, PARAM
FROM(
      SELECT X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.ASSESSMENTID, CAST(X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.THIRDPARTY AS VARCHAR(3)) AS THIRDP,
      X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, 
      X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.CLAIMDATE, X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE.SETTLEDAMOUNT, 'Q2' as PARAM
      FROM X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT
      LEFT JOIN X.XCLAIMTREATMENT
      ON X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.ASSESSMENTID = X.XCLAIMTREATMENT.ASSESSMENTID
      LEFT JOIN X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE
      ON X.XCLAIMTREATMENT.TREATMENTID = X.XCLAIMTREATMENTINVOICE.TREATMENTID
      WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,to_date(X.XCLAIMASSESSMENT.CLAIMDATE))< 25)
      GROUP BY ASSESSMENTID, CLAIMDATE, FIRSTDIAGNOSIS, AFFECTEDSYSTEMDESC, THIRDP, PARAM
      HAVING SUM(SETTLEDAMOUNT) > 50000;
```